# How to know in Haskell in what row and column of a table ([[a]]) you are

Tags: haskell

I want to make a sudoku solver in Haskell (as an exercise). My idea is:

I have `t :: [[Int]]` representing a 9x9 grid so that it contains 0 in an empty field and 1-9 in a solved field.

A function `solve :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]` returns the solved sudoku.

Here is a rough sketch of it (i'd like to point out i'm a beginner, i know it is not the most optimal code):

```
solve :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
solve t
        | null (filter (elem 0) t) = t
        | t /= beSmart t           = solve (beSmart t)
        | otherwise                = guess t
```

The function `beSmart :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]` tries to solve it by applying some solving algorithms, but if methodical approach fails (`beSmart` returns the unchanged sudoku table in that case) it should try to guess some numbers (and i'll think of that function later). In order to fill in an empty field, i have to find it first. And here's the problem:

```
beSmart :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
beSmart t = map f t 
        where f row 
                | elem 0 row = map unsolvedRow row
                | otherwise  = row                            
                         where unsolvedRow a
                                | a == 0    = tryToDo t r c --?!?!?!?! skip
                                | otherwise = a
```

The function `tryToDo :: [[Int]]] -> Int -> Int - > Int` needs the row and column of the field i'm trying to change, but i have no idea how to get that information. How do i get from `map` what element of the list i am in at the moment? Or is there a better way to move around in the table? I come from iterative and procedural programing and i understand that perhaps my approach to the problem is wrong when it comes to functional programing.

Comment: You could zip the indices with the rows/columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is not really an answer to your question, but I would argue, that usually you would want a different representation (one that keeps a more detailed view of what you know about the sudoku puzzle, in your attempted solution you can only distinguish a solved cell from a cell that is free to assume any value). Sudoku is a classical instance of [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem). Where modern approaches offer many fairly general smart *propagation* rules, such as *unit propagation* (blocking a digit in neighboring cells once used somewhere), but also many other, see [AC-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC-3_algorithm) for further details. Other related topics include [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)/[SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) and you might find the algorithm [DPLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) also interesting. In the heart of most solvers there usually is some kind of a [search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_search) engine to deal with non-determinism (not every instance must have a single solution that is directly derivable from the initial configuration of the instance by application of inference rules). There are also techniques such as [CDCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-Driven_Clause_Learning) to direct the search.

---

To address the question in the title, to know where you are, its probably best if you abstract the traversal of your *table* so that each step has access to the coordinates, you can for example `zip` a list of rows with `[0..]` (`zip [0..] rows`) to number the rows, when you then `map` a function over the zipped lists, you will have access to pairs `(index, row)`, the same applies to columns. Just a sketch of the idea:

```
mapTable :: (Int -> Int -> a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
mapTable f rows = map (\(r, rs) -> mapRow (f r) rs) $ zip [0..] rows

mapRow :: (Int -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapRow f cols = map (uncurry f) $ zip [0..] cols
```

or use `fold` to turn your table into something else (for example to search for a *unit cell*):

```
foldrTable :: (Int -> Int -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> [[a]] -> b
foldrTable f z rows = foldr (\(r, rs) b -> foldrRow (f r) b rs) z $ zip [0..] rows

foldrRow :: (Int -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldrRow f z cols = foldr (uncurry f) z $ zip [0..] cols
```

to find which cell is *unital*:

```
foldrTable
    (\x y v acc -> if length v == 1 then Just (x, y) else acc)
    Nothing
    [[[1..9],[1..9],[1..9]],[[1..9],[1..9],[1..9]],[[1..9],[1],[1..9]]]
```

by using `Monoid` you can refactor it:

```
import Data.Monoid

foldrTable' :: Monoid b => (Int -> Int -> a -> b) -> [[a]] -> b
foldrTable' f rows = foldrTable (\r c a b -> b <> f r c a) mempty rows

unit :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
unit x y c | length c == 1 = Just (x, y)
           | otherwise     = Nothing

firstUnit :: [[[a]]] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
firstUnit = getFirst . foldrTable' (\r c v -> First $ unit r c v)
```

so now you would do

```
firstUnit [[[1..9],[1..9],[1..9]],[[1,2],[3,4],[5]]]
```

to obtain

```
Just (1, 2)
```

correctly determining that the first unit cell is at position `1,2` in the table.

Comment: I did not want to spoil it to you. If you want more details just indicate so :)

Comment: So this would be part of the "guessing" algorithm once the proper one is done (It's a strict set of rules, i doubt it's less efficient ). Would it be practical to turn the sudoku table into a graph with 81 nodes, and each node having it's value and pointers to the 20 other fields it should not have the same value as? I am trying to replicate the map colouring problem, but am perhaps doing it roughly.

Comment: Normally, you would make every cell a list of all possibilities, i.e. `[1..9]` initially, over time you would remove possibilities that are in conflict with neighboring cells, when a cell becomes unit (i.e. a list of length 1, you can *unit propagate* this fact to remove possibilities in neighboring cells). When a cell becomes empty, you found a dead end and need to *backtrack* in your search. So it is fine to represent the partial solution with a table of cells that instead of being either 0 or a definitive digit keep all the possibilities.

Comment: Whenever you cannot propagate any more facts, you make a non-deterministic guess (i.e. you resort to a primitive search). Eventually (if the initial state of the sudoku did not include conflicts) you will end up with a table where every cell has exactly one possibility, which is your solution. So the initial state of a sudoku already fixes some of the cells to singleton lists. The fact that you model each cell with a list of possibilities is closely related to *domain allocation* from CSP.

Answer (score 0):

`[[Int]]` is a good type for a sodoku. But map does not give any info regarding the place it is in. This is one of the ideas behind map.

You could zip together the index with the value. But a better idea would be to pass the whole `[[Int]]` and the indexes to to the function. So its type would become:

```
f :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
```

inside the function you can now access the current element by

```
t !! x !! y
```

Comment: So i should remove `map` and perhaps iterate field to field with recursions version of `for (r=0,...,r++){for(c=0,...,c++)}`? I just hoped there is a recursion-friendly solution

Comment: @someoneb100, one useful function is `mapWithIndex :: (Int -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. You can similarly write indexed versions of `foldMap` and `traverse`.

Answer (score 0):

Already did this a while ago as a learning example. It is definitely not the nicest solution, but it worked for me.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Char

sodoku="\
 \-9-----1-\
 \8-4-2-3-7\
 \-6-9-7-2-\
 \--5-3-1--\
 \-7-5-1-3-\
 \--3-9-8--\
 \-2-8-5-6-\
 \1-7-6-4-9\
 \-3-----8-"

sodoku2="\
\----13---\
\7-5------\
\1----547-\
\--418----\
\951-67843\
\-2---4--1\
\-6235-9-7\
\--7-98--4\
\89----1-5"

data Position = Position (Int, Int) deriving (Show)

data Sodoku = Sodoku [Int] 

insertAtN :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insertAtN n y xs = intercalate [y] . groups n $ xs
  where
    groups n xs = takeWhile (not.null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt n) $ xs

instance Show Sodoku where
   show (Sodoku s) = (insertAtN 9 '\n' $ map intToDigit s) ++ "\n"

convertDigit :: Char -> Int
convertDigit x = case x of 
    '-' -> 0
    x -> if digit>=1 && digit<=9 then
            digit
         else
            0
         where digit=digitToInt x

convertSodoku :: String -> Sodoku
convertSodoku x = Sodoku $ map convertDigit x

adjacentFields :: Position -> [Position]
adjacentFields (Position (x,y)) = 
    [Position (i,y) | i<-[0..8]] ++ 
    [Position (x,j) | j<-[0..8]] ++ 
    [Position (u+i,v+j) | i<-[0..2], j<-[0..2]] 
    where 
        u=3*(x `div` 3)
        v=3*(y `div` 3)

positionToField :: Position -> Int
positionToField (Position (x,y)) = x+y*9

fieldToPosition :: Int -> Position
fieldToPosition x = Position (x `mod` 9, x `div` 9)

getDigit :: Sodoku -> Position -> Int
getDigit (Sodoku x) pos = x !! (positionToField pos )

getAdjacentDigits :: Sodoku -> Position -> [Int]
getAdjacentDigits s p = nub digitList 
    where 
        digitList=filter (\x->x/=0) $ map (getDigit s) (adjacentFields p)

getFreePositions :: Sodoku -> [Position]
getFreePositions (Sodoku x) = map fieldToPosition $ elemIndices 0 x

isSolved :: Sodoku -> Bool
isSolved s = (length $ getFreePositions s)==0

isDeadEnd :: Sodoku -> Bool
isDeadEnd s = any (\x->x==0) $ map length $ map (getValidDigits s)$ getFreePositions s

setDigit :: Sodoku -> Position -> Int -> Sodoku
setDigit (Sodoku x) pos digit = Sodoku $ h ++ [digit] ++ t
    where 
        field=positionToField pos
        h=fst $ splitAt field x
        t=tail$ snd $ splitAt field x

getValidDigits :: Sodoku -> Position -> [Int]        
getValidDigits s p = [1..9] \\ (getAdjacentDigits s p)


-- Select numbers with few possible choices first to increase execution time       
sortImpl :: (Position, [Int]) -> (Position, [Int]) -> Ordering
sortImpl (_, i1) (_, i2) 
    | length(i1)<length(i2) = LT
    | length(i1)>length(i2) = GT
    | length(i1)==length(i2) = EQ

selectMoves :: Sodoku -> Maybe (Position, [Int])
selectMoves s
    | length(posDigitList)>0 = Just (head posDigitList)
    | otherwise = Nothing
    where
        posDigitList=sortBy sortImpl $ zip freePos validDigits
        validDigits=map (getValidDigits s) freePos
        freePos=getFreePositions s

createMoves :: Sodoku -> [Sodoku]
createMoves s=
    case selectMoves s of
        Nothing -> []
        (Just (pos, digits)) -> [setDigit s pos d|d<-digits] 

solveStep :: Sodoku -> [Sodoku]
solveStep s 
    | (isSolved s) = [s]
    | (isDeadEnd s )==True = []
    | otherwise = createMoves s 

solve :: Sodoku -> [Sodoku]        
solve s 
    | (isSolved s) = [s]
    | (isDeadEnd s)==True = []
    | otherwise=concat $ map solve (solveStep s)


s=convertSodoku sodoku2

readSodoku :: String -> Sodoku
readSodoku x = Sodoku []
```